# Problems with graphics trying to install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have a fresh `14.04 LTS 64-bit` USB-Stick that I am able to boot from. (With `nomodeset`) I get the black-white menu on which I can tell to boot Ubuntu without installation properly.

After that comes the problem: I get a weird kind of display error. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmtNJ.jpg).

It's extremely hard to set things up from there, I can type blind but I cannot see what e.g. a terminal prints to the screen. I also cannot control with the mouse (technically the mouse works, but I simply don't see what my mouse is doing)

I managed to blind-type `xrandr`, save that onto  a USB disk, and here is the output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       76.0*
```

My screen supports `1920x1080`, so apparently something is detected wrongly anyways.

I have a `NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M` installed into an All-In-One-PC by Sony VAIO.

Still, remember, I have nothing but this bugged view of Ubuntu and nothing else (I have access to a 32-bit old laptop which is running Ubuntu as well, note though that I am not going to be able to boot my live usb stick there because the stick is 64bit and the old laptop is 32bit).

Comment: What graphics is the computer using?

Comment: @Wilf derp, see the edit. It's a NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my monitor did not support 61/76Hz, which was the auto-detected setting.

I connected a secondary monitor and configured the first monitor to use a 60Hz profile, the screen turned on and the video was no longer glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or by blind-installing ssh server through apt-get and connecting from the laptop, or making a remote shell of nc and mkfifo).

Then use some guide to reinstall nvidia or mesa drivers.